# ssh (config file) & git clone not connecting on the the right port?

Tags: git, github, ssh

So where I am at port 22 seems to be blocked. I changes my ssh config file (as you can tell i've been playing around with a little bit):

```
#Host ssh.github.com
#  Hostname ssh.github.com
#  Port 443

#Host github.com
#  Hostname github.com
#  Port 443

Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
```

When I do the following it works as expected (previously I would get a connection timeout):

```
ssh -T git@github.com
git@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

but when I do a `git clone` its still trying to connect over port `22`:

```
git clone git@github.com:<MyUser>/<MyRepo>.git
Cloning into '<MyRep>'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does anyone know why its still using `port 22` with `git clone`? FYI I'm using windows.

Comment: Your ssh config is for `ssh.github.com`, not `github.com`.

Comment: @Brian61354270 weird i also use wsl some so i tried there & it worked fine (config was the same what i posted in wsl). I tried to change it to just `github.com` from `ssh.github.com` though. Maybe i have to reboot :P? I did restart the ssh service so who knows :P.